# Google analytic negative item price value?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to send a negative item price value to google analytic within e-commerce.
I've made an email 'party' with some fellow at google but no possible solution so far!

So the situation: 
Negative item price value is work as soon as the item transaction id is the same and the negative item price is less or the same as the positive was before(It has to be a transaction previously). But you can not send in negative item price value other way.

Which is a big problem cause for instance if you have two property in e-commerce(deposit,withdraw) the revenue value would be deposit-withdraw and both positive numbers (in this case cause I can't send in negative number) and the analytic make an sum for revenue which is completely wrong. If anybody has any idea how could I solve this problem I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit a negative item price, rather a negative transaction for a refund.